# Find min/max $\|x\|_{1}$ subject to $Ax = b$, using the simplex method

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, binary-programming

> Let $Ax = b$ be a linear system with $a_{i,j} \in \{0,1\}$ and $b_i \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$. The constraints on $x$ are $x_i \in \{0,1\}$. 
>   We suppose that the system admits at least one solution.
>
> How do I obtain the minimum and maximum amount of $1$'s in my solution
>   vector?

---

**Example:**

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
x = \begin{bmatrix}
 1\\
 3\\
 2\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

In this case it is quite clear that $\|x\|_{1} \geq 3$ but how do I generalize this? Apparently this can be done with the simplex algorithm. I have never done any linear programming and would appreciate an explanation of this method (maybe on the example above).

I am trying to understand the linear programming
part (page 16) of the following article:

- Andrew Fowler, Andrew Young, [Minesweeper: a statistical and
  computational analysis](http://www.minesweeper.info/articles/MinesweeperStatisticalComputationalAnalysis.pdf), 2004.

Answer (score 0):

Optimal point of minimize problem is allowing as:
optimal value:3, optimal point:{x1 -> 0, x2 -> 0, x3 -> 0, x4 -> 0, x5 -> 1, x6 -> 0, x7 -> 0, x8 -> 0, x9 -> 1, x10 -> 1, x11 -> 0, x12 -> 0}
Optimal point of maximize problem is allowing as:
optimal value:4, optimal point:{x1 -> 0, x2 -> 0, x3 -> 0, x4 -> 0, x5 -> 0, x6 -> 0, x7 -> 1, x8 -> 0, x9 -> 1, x10 -> 0, x11 -> 1, x12 -> 1}
Above problem is a kind of pure binary linear programming problem.
I have new and good algorithm and software to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Given an underdetermined linear system $\mathrm A \mathrm x = \mathrm b$ in $\mathrm x \in \{0,1\}^n$, we would like to extremize the number of ones in the solution. Since $x_i \in \{0,1\}$, there is no need to extremize $\|\mathrm x\|_1$. Instead, we extremize $1_n^T \mathrm x$. We then have the binary program

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{extremize} & 1_n^T \mathrm x\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm A \mathrm x = \mathrm b\\ & \mathrm x \in \{0,1\}^{n}\end{array}$$

which can be rewritten as an **integer program** (IP)

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{extremize} & 1^T \mathrm x\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm A \mathrm x = \mathrm b\\ & 0_n \leq \mathrm x \leq 1_n\\ & \mathrm x \in \mathbb Z^n\end{array}$$

Relaxing the integrality constraint, we then have a **linear program** (LP)

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{extremize} & 1^T \mathrm x\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm A \mathrm x = \mathrm b\\ & 0_n \leq \mathrm x \leq 1_n\\ & \mathrm x \in \mathbb R^n\end{array}$$

which can be solved using, say, the simplex method. Of course, there is no guarantee that the solution to the LP is the same as the solution to the IP.